# Bug with DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm currently facing a weird problem. We are using date picker, witch by the way, it's amazing. But we encounter a weird problem. 
The date picker is include and displaying on a btstrap modal, but it return the date only on the first modal (so for the Ranch.first)

My code :

*My button view =*

```
    <div style= 'z-index: 99; position: fixed;right:5%;  bottom:5%;text-decoration: none;'>
  <div class="add_task_layout" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#MyNewTask1' aria-hidden="true" remote="true">
    +
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal New_task_layout1 (click. on Add layout and select a Ranch) -->
  <div id='MyNewTask1' class='modal fade' role='dialog' aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class='content'>

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Select the ranch</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <% current_user.ranches.each do |ranch| %>
            <div class="btn btn-default" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#MyNewTask2<%=ranch.id %>' remote="true" data-dismiss="modal"  >
              <%=ranch.name %>
            </div>

          <%end%>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- /Modal New_task_layout1 -->

<!-- Modal New_task_layout2 (click. on the ranch and create the task) -->
<% current_user.ranches.each do |ranch|%>
  <div id='MyNewTask2<%=ranch.id %>' class='modal fade' role='dialog' aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class='content'>

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">New task for <%=ranch.name %></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= render 'tasks/form3', ranch: ranch %>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<%end%>
<!-- /Modal New_task_layout2 -->
```

*My form3 =*

```
<%= simple_form_for([ranch, ranch.tasks.build]) do |f| %>

  <div class="input-group" >

    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New task", style: "width:50%; border: solid 0.1px" %>

     <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <div class="dropdown_menu_area">
                <%=f.input :staff_ids, :as => :check_boxes, label: false, id:"check" do %>
                  <%=f.collection_check_boxes :staff_ids, ranch.staffs, :id, :name do |b|%>
                    <li class="dropdown_menu_line">
                      <%=b.check_box + b.label%>
                    </li>
                  <%end%>
                <%end%>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>


    <%= f.text_field :date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker',style: "width: 10%; border: solid 0.1px"  %>
    <div style= "margin: 10px;">
      <%= f.submit%>
    </div>

  </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      autoclose: true
    });
    </script>

<% end %>
```

So if you have any idea from where can come from the mistake, you'll be my hero !!

Comment: Looks like the script is *inside* the form... the form that is repeated multiple times on the page... perhaps that code only needs to appear once on the page? Or else it needs to be specific to the individual form? (This is a guess... not sure if it will fix the bug, but it's probably a good idea anyway). Aside: as a veteran of the Y2K bug... please use `'yyyy-mm-dd'` :)

Comment: @TarynEast ahah yes but without this format, I could not save the date. And I would be honored if my web app survive until 2100 ahah. 
I'd try your solution moving the script but I still have this stupid error. But thanks for your answer master

Comment: A 4-digit year isn't just so your script survives the next century... it also disambiguates: 05-01-06 -> is that 5th Jan 2006 or 6th Jan 2005 ? Your computer might know... but your customers might not...

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for that, I maid the corrections. By the way, you don't have any other issues that I can test for my error ?

Comment: What does the javascript console say? are any errors popping up there?

Comment: if you already put the js on a single file, you could try to use the jQuery(function(){}) to run it only when the page is fully loaded

Comment: Hi, @Alexis, thanks for your answer ! As you con see on my second bloc of code, I implement the js on each form. I don't really know how jq work, so can you help me with that ? What I should change or implement in this bloc of code ?

Comment: remove the javascript from the partial and add the code to your application.js file, i usually use coffeescript, but i believe it should be something like this ```jQuery(function(){$('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      autoclose: true
    });})``` this means basically load this bit of code when the page is fully loaded